# I am creating simple animation of Solar System using acm.graphics.movePolar() and i don't know how can I change velocity of planets

Tags: java, acm.graphics

I was trying to change velocity by changing value of degree, which changes on each iteration.
But if I have all planets in the same cycle, they anyway move synchronically.

```
for (double i = 180; i != -180; i-=0.5) { 
    planetList[0].movePolar((Math.PI * ORBITAL_DIAMETER) / 720.0,I); 
    planetList[1].movePolar((Math.PI * ORBITAL_DIAMETER * 2) / 720.0, i); 
}

for (double i = 180; i != -180; i--) {
    planetList[0].movePolar((Math.PI * ORBITAL_DIAMETER) / 360.0, i);
    planetList[1].movePolar((Math.PI * ORBITAL_DIAMETER * 2) / 360.0, i);       
}
```

I tried diffrent variations of cycles, and adding coefficients in movePolar(COEFFICIENT * double r, double theta * COEFFICIENT).

So, I understood that problem can be solved by creating several cycles, but then one planet will move, second will stay till first won't finish.

Is there any chance to add some coefficient in order to increase speed of rotation?

Comment: Not related to the solution, but while working with floating type values (float or double), as far as possible, don't use exact comparisons like `i != -180`.  Instead, use `i >= -180`.

Comment: Because there can be some randomly small values like 0.50000001 or something like that? Or it's simply more readable?

Comment: Yes, that exact reason..  `i` may never be exactly equal to `-180`, but `-179.999999....` or `-180.00000....`, and may never break out from the loop. Not saying that it would definitely be like this, but usually have to take care of this with floating point variables.

Comment: Also looking at https://cs.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/jtf/javadoc/student/acm/graphics/GObject.html#movePolar(double,%20double), it seems the 2nd parameter is theta - the angle.  So, 2nd code piece that has `i--` that is 1 degree of movement should be faster as compared to the 1st code piece that has `i -= 0.5` - half a degree per iteration of the loop.

Comment: Yes, it is faster, but i want different speed for each planet, but if I do cycles like above, all of them move with equal velocity. I was thinking about one cycle, where angle changes on 1 degree each iteration for earth, and another one in which delta is 2 deegres per iteration, but I don't know how to implement all of this conditions in one cycle.

Comment: Looking closer at the JavaDoc, it seems this movePolar is not for an orbital movement but just to move an object from its current location to `r` distance and at `theta` degree.  And to move at different speeds, you have to change the `r` for each planet.

Comment: In your case `r` is same for both the planets.  If a planet is moving faster, then `r` should be higher for that. I.e. in the same time period, how much it would travel in the orbit around the Sun.

Comment: Oh, I just miss-typed, ORBITAL_DIAMETER should be multiplied by (numberPlanetInArray+1).

Comment: So (Math.PI * ORBITAL_DIAMETER) is the length of orbit for the 1st planet, and (Math.PI * ORBITAL_DIAMETER * 2) is the length of orbit for the 2nd planet. Radius of first orbit is half of radius of the second one.

Comment: I am not a scientist, but I love astronomy.  My suggestion is check this - https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/factsheet/.  Here, each planet has Orbital Period (days). E.g. Earth's is 365.2. So, in a day 360 degrees/365.2 = 0.98576 degrees per day. You can find this at any interval, an hour also if needed. Then using trigo, at this angle (keep angle changing differently per planet), at r distance (each planet at a different distance), what would be its (x,y) co-ordinates - calculate that and move object there.

Comment: Thanks a lot, will think about how to get this done in one cycle.

Answer (score 0):

As given in the comment, adding an answer so that I can paste an image.

[image]

Keep different r = radius of the planet's orbit, and keep theta changing differently per unit of time.
And calculate x & y co-ordinates of each planet based on their own r & theta.
Set the exact co-ordinates of each planet using this.

Remember to add (cx,cy), the co-ordinates of the sun to the calculated x & y of each planet to make it orbit around the sun.

Something like this - Not tried in Java, you may need to adjust/correct. But something like this:

```
for(time = 0; time < numberOfTimeIterations; time++) {  // Or while(true) if you want it to keep going
    for(i = 0;i < numberOfPlanets;i++) {
        currentAngle[i] -= angleMovement[i];
        if(currentAngle[i] < 0) currentAngle[i] += 360;
        double radians = Math.toRadians(currentAngle[i]);
        double x = sunx + radius[i] * Math.cos(radians);
        double y = suny + radius[i] * Math.sin(radians);
        planet[i].move(x,y)
    }
}
```

```
angleMovement[i] = calculated per same time interval angular movement of each planet
currentAngle[i] = Keeps increasing based on planet's angular movement each time interval
radius[i] = Radius of each planet's orbit
sunx, suny = x-y co-ordinates of the Sun
```

Planet orbit radius and orbital movement can be found at - https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/factsheet/

Total 360 degrees / Orbital Period (days) = degrees per day

E.g. for earth

360/365.2 = 0.98576 degrees per day.

If the animation is to be done per hour, then 0.98576/24 = 0.041073 degrees per hour.

Similarly calculate and initialize for each planet.

Radius of the orbit is given in that fact sheet as "Distance from Sun (10<sup>6</sup> km)"

This calculation works. Built a small swing app...

[image]

[image]

[image]

S is the Sun in the centre.
0 to 8 planets, Mercury to Pluto.
Zoom-in & Zoom-out - zoom factor changed in 3rd image to show all 9
Time delay is milliseconds to sleep before the next iteration. Faster or Slower animation.

But, the calculation works!!

Comment: So you suggest using simple move() method?

Comment: Yes, I think so...